# Setting spellcheck language in Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

I'm trying to create a simple editable field (for posting) while combining a spellcheck:

```
<div contenteditable="contenteditable" spellcheck="spellcheck" lang="en">text</div>
```

(http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/17-spellcheck.html)

It works, but on Google Chrome, the spellchecker doesn't detect the language. (despite the specified @lang attribute)

The "bug" was fixed in Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=338427

But I can't find anything about Google Chrome's implementation of this. Is there a way to notify the spellchecker about the expected language in an HTML5 field? Maybe something in the `<head>` like `charset`, `meta lang`, etc?

Comment: I couldn't find any documentation/solution for chrome either... I really would like to know more about the chrome implementation

Comment: Found two issue about it https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=5102 and https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1834

Comment: Seems to be a bug. This is the most recent issue I have found for this: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=389498, from June 2014.

Comment: Since this is a bug you may be intrested in some JS solution, there are a few, ie. http://www.javascriptspellcheck.com/, https://code.google.com/p/bjspell/ but I've heard voices they are experiencing some performance issues.

Answer (score 13):

The `spellcheck` attribute is not implemented in all browsers yet. If it is, there are some bugs need to be fixed.

<del>According to W3Schools:...</del> *(**Update**: now [supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=spellcheck) by "**all**" browsers.)*

<del>When I visit the link you mentioned above (in Chrome 22) there are some bugs. The spellchecker says on "key" it's mispelled, and double clicking on some words makes it indicated as misspelled, too. I had Hungarian selected as spellchecking language.</del>

**NOTE:** The language can be changed by right-clicking on the input, but you need to reload the page.

Also there are some browsers where spellchecking is turned of in the settings.

As I saw in the comments, bwitkowicz mentioned a solution with JS.

```js
function updateStatus() {
    console.log("updating");
    $("#spellStatus").text( String( $("#textContent").attr("spellcheck") ) );
    $("#editStatus").text(  String( $("#textContent").attr("contentEditable") ) );    
}

$(function() {
    updateStatus();
    
    $("#spell").ready(function() {
        console.log("spell");
        $("#textContent").attr( "spellcheck", function(ix,old) {
            old = old === "false" ? false : true;
            console.log("setting " + (!old));
            return old;
        });
    });
    $("#edit").ready(function() {
        console.log("edit");
        $("#textContent").attr( "contentEditable", function(ix,old) {
            old = old === "false" ? true : false;
            console.log("setting " + (!old));
            return !old;
        });
    });
    
    $("#spell, #edit").ready(updateStatus);
    
});
```

```css
#spell, #edit, #spellStatus, #editStatus {
     display: none;   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><button id="spell">Toggle Spellcheck</button><span id="spellStatus"></span></div>
<div><button id="edit">Toggle Editable</button><span id="editStatus"></span></div>
<div id="textContent" style="padding: 5px; border: 1px solid black;">
Here is some texxt with spellung erreurs. Also you have to click inside the div to chekc erorrrrs.
</div>
```

### UPDATE:

```
<html lang="en">
<body>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <textarea lang="fr"></textarea>
  <div lang="ru">
    <textarea></textarea>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In this HTML snippet, the first `<textarea>` will be spell checked in English, the second in French, and the third in Russian.

If an element specifies a language, and the user has no dictionary installed for that language, spell check is disabled by default, although the user may choose to manually enable it.

Hope that helps some way. The only problem is you need to click inside the div (if you use the JS solution) to check misspelling.

Comment: Also check out `<div contenteditable="contenteditable" spellcheck="true" lang="en">text</div>` if it works. (Changed spellcheck to true.)

Comment: The question is about setting **the language** of spellchecking for elements.

Comment: I updated my answer above however it seems like Chrome doesn't support this yet. Or maybe older versions. I recommend you to read more about it here, hopefully there is something you can work with. https://blog.whatwg.org/the-road-to-html-5-spellchecking  Sorry for misunderstanding.

Comment: As an alternative solution you could tweak with [JSpell](http://www.jspell.com/html-spell-checker.html)