# Chrome style spellcheck errors using CSS or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

My problem is, that I need to change the language of a spellingerror in web. Disable it is not an option:

I tried many solutions, but all properties like `::spelling-error` and `:webkit-spell-check` are not supported.

Is there a way to do this?

```css
::spelling-error {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p spellcheck="true" contenteditable>
  word that doesnt exist arberbicee
</p>
```

PS: Can also use JS

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Over-ride Chrome Browser spell check language using JQuery or JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252737/over-ride-chrome-browser-spell-check-language-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: well, this spellcheck library might help, but to be specific: I want to use the default spellcheck of chrome and just use a different style. I use it for a closed environment, where i can only inject JS, and any thridparty library with large size slows donw the already untraslow pages and it gets obious

Answer (score 0):

As you indicated in the questions, the ::spelling-error (and also ::grammar-error) CSS pseudo elements allow you to customize the markers drawn by the browser for spelling errors. It is now supported in Chrome and other chromium-based browsers, and should be coming sometime soonish to other browsers.