# How can I add spell check in the textarea/textbox which should work for any regional language

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I wanted to add a spellcheck feature to my textbox and text area but it should work for any language not only English. for example, if my language is french then it should check spelling based on french and if my language is English then it should do for English.

Comment: Does this answer your question ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21306199/setting-spellcheck-language-in-google-chrome

Comment: that's a browser setting, isn't it? I know I set mine to Australian English - has nothing to do with any websites I visit, I control my language

Comment: @AshwinR - a lot has changed in over 6 years :p